# flip two values in rows of 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, 2d, flip

I wrote the following code to flip two values in rows of 2d numpy array. However, I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. thanks in advance

```
def mtn(offg):
    for row in range(offg.shape[0]):
        point1 = random.randint(0, 139)
        point2 = random.randint(0, 139)
        temp = offg[row, point1]
        offg[row, point1] = offg[row, point2]
        offg[row, point2] = temp
    return offg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use advanced indexing:

```
offg[:,[p1, p2]] = offg[:,[p2, p1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if points are same in each row, u can use code like

```py
tmp = offg[:,p1].copy()
offg[:,p1] = offg[:,p2]
offg[:,p2] = tmp
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately they are not the same

Comment: So I don't see some problems in your way

Comment: yes but I was looking for more advanced way to do it like the advanced indexing indicated by tstanisl above